# Why laravel installer returns command not found?

Tags: laravel

I try to install new laravel app on fresh ubuntu installation, but I got error :

```
master@master-laptop:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar$ composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
Changed current directory to /home/master/.config/composer
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/installer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
13 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
master@master-laptop:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar$ export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
master@master-laptop:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar$ laravel new NewLivewireApp --jet
laravel: command not found
```

Why I got error ? Is 1.1 valid installation for mopdern laravel app?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check when this was released? v1.1 is more than seven years old. Also, what did you try to resolve the problem?

Comment: remove the version in your command `composer global require "laravel/installer"`

Comment: Without the version I got version ^4.2 for laravel/installer and next error anyway : $ export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
$ laravel new NewLivewireApp --jet
laravel: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I salved the issue with commands :

```
nano ~/.bash_profile 

export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and it works for me !

Answer (score 2):

you must add a composer autoloader to your OS path.

add this code to the end if you are using Linux.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

File:

```
~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This solution also works for mac users.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to just use composers built in installer, which i use on a regularly basis.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-app
```

Answer (score 0):

`composer create-project foo/bar` command creates a new project from **packagist.org**

`composer require foo/bar` gets the module(library) from **packagist.org**

so you should use

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel mylaravelproject
```

for detail look at this link

https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel

Comment: But does this format support --jet option, as I got error with this format : composer create-project laravel/laravel NewLivewireApp --jet

                                                          
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The "--jet" option does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
composer global require laravel/installer

laravel new example-app
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: If the OP states that running `laravel new`  does not work  after running `composer global require laravel/installer`, what else does your answer do to resolve this?